# Angularjs not picking up data-src

Tags: angularjs

For some reason Angular isn't catching my data-src

When I do this:

```
<div foo data-src="{{ my_url }}"></div>
```

I get back nothing. However, it works when I manually type it: i.e

```
<div foo data-src="blah"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

---

More of my code:

```
var foo = angular.module('foo', []);

foo.directive('foo', function ($document, $rootScope, $http, $resource) {

return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: true,
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        console.log(attrs.src)
      }
  });
```

Comment: My *guess* is that angular evaluates your data-src before it evaluates `{{ my_url }}`

Comment: @Tom Yes, I'm pretty sure this is the problem. Would you happen to know a fix?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `data-ng-src`? The browser evaluates the source before angular replaces the content. You can use `ng-src` or `data-ng-src`, that should work, but it will send two requests: one invalid without the placeholder filled in, then the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Edit]**

I forgot to use camelCase for the attribute name when calling `attrs.$observe()`. Also, it looks like you **do** need to use ng-data-source). Correction made below...

You want to use `attrs.$observe()` in the link function for your directive. Angular will watch the attribute and execute a callback so the directive can be notified when the value of the interpolated expression changes.

Here's a link to a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/Xktuz/) created by Mark Rajcok that demonstrates it. And a link to the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24compile.directive.Attributes) as well.

Finally, here is some sample code using your directive:

```
var foo = angular.module('foo', []);

foo.directive('foo', function ($document, $rootScope, $http, $resource) {

return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: true,
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        attrs.$observe('ngDataSrc', function(newValue) {
          console.log('interpolated value', newValue);
        }
      }
  });
```

Comment: The documentation says it will call the callback immediately (on the next $digest) when you do the $observe, and then anytime the value changes. Is the value undefined the first time? If so, maybe you can just ignore that the first time...

Comment: Thank you. I ended up doing this `if (newValue != undefined)`